# How do I pass in a parameter value to a vbscript I want to run

Tags: vbscript, moveit

I am trying to write a script to create a flg file after a filemovement that is empty but just indicates the file moved before it has been sent successfully. Since this will be used repeately for many differnt file movements with many different destination locations and many differnt names for the flg file, I want to send in parameters to the script.

I have successfully gotten the script to create the file if I hardcode the directory and filename values. But I can't figure out how I would sent the variable values that my MoveIt task has already defined and populated into the script to be the values of `strDirectory` and `strFile` variables in the script.

I tried just setting the parameters for the process in MoveIt using the same name as the variables in the script and that didn't work.

I tried something called `WScript.Arguments`, and that didn't work:

```
strDirectory = Wscript.Arguments.Item(0) 

strFile = Wscript.Arguments.Item(1)
```

Not sure what else to try.

Comment: How *exactly* did it "not work"? The code snippet you posted will take the first 2 arguments to the script and assign them to the variables `strDirectory` and `strFile`. How were you calling the script, and what were you doing with the variables next?

Comment: @angar it errorerd on the first of those two lines. Error was: Error running script Flag File on : Error in script at line 7 char 1: Object required: ''

Comment: It is called from a MoveIt task

Comment: They're probably using their own script engine, which doesn't provide a `WScript` object. The [documentation](https://moveitsupport.ipswitch.com/SUPPORT/miapiwin/online-manual.htm) has some code samples, but I'm not sure how much that's going to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use MIGetTaskParam(ParamName) inside the VB script and pass the directory and file names as parameters on the script itself.

For example, on the process step add a parameter called "PATH" and populate it with the macro [FullPath].

Inside the script get the value with something like:
myfullpath = MIGetTaskParam(PATH)

Unfortunately there is not a macro that will give you just the full path without the filename, so you'll have to split it up in VB yourself.